# css to align the image to be on the center of heading and paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have the below code

```css
body.about-page ul.about-div {width: 100%; position: relative;float: left; padding: 0 10px; }
body.about-page ul.about-div li {width: 100%; float: left; position: relative; display: block; padding: 8px 25px; border-bottom: 1px #c7c7c7 solid; background-color: #fff;}
body.about-page ul.about-div li img {float: left; position: relative; display: inline-block; }
body.about-page ul.about-div li h3 {display: inline-block; float: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 26px;  padding-left: 10px;}
body.about-page ul.about-div li.active {padding: 17px 25px; background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 0; }
body.about-page ul.about-div li.active h3 span {font-size: 11px; line-height: 12px; color: #646464; display: block; }
```

```html
<ul class="about-div">
   <li class="active"><img src="http://oi64.tinypic.com/v7qo8h.jpg" alt="">     
    <h3>User</h3>
    <span>My Profile</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

What I want is, the image on the left and User and My profile be on top and bottom such that whole image is covered.

I hope the questions is clear. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vk8Lp62q/).

Answer (score 0):

> try this may be this will help you

```css
body.about-page ul.about-div {width: 100%; position: relative;float: left; padding: 0 10px; }
body.about-page ul.about-div li {width: 100%; float: left; position: relative; display: block; padding: 8px 25px; border-bottom: 1px #c7c7c7 solid; background-color: #fff;}
body.about-page ul.about-div li img {float: left; position: relative; display: inline-block; }
body.about-page ul.about-div li h3 {display: inline-block; float: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 26px;  padding-left: 10px;}
body.about-page ul.about-div li.active {padding: 17px 25px; background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 0; }
body.about-page ul.about-div li.active h3 span {font-size: 11px; line-height: 12px; color: #646464; display: block; }
li{
  display:inline-block;
}
img{
  float:left;
}
h3,span{margin:0 0 0 10px;float:left;}
span{margin-left:38px}
```

```html
<ul class="about-div">
<li class="active">
<img src="http://oi64.tinypic.com/v7qo8h.jpg" alt=""><h3>User</h3><br><span>My Profile</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you if still need any modifications, let me know

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you exactly want but may be this will help you

```css
ul.about-div {
  width: 100%; 
  position: relative;
  float: left; 
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.about-div li {
  width: 100%; 
  float: left; 
  position: relative; 
  display: block; 
  padding: 8px 25px; 
  border-bottom: 1px #c7c7c7 solid; 
  background-color: #fff;
}
ul.about-div li img {
  float: left; 
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.about-div li h3 {
  display:block; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  line-height: 18px;  
  padding-left: 35px; 
  margin:0;
}
ul.about-div li.active {
  padding: 17px 25px; 
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 0;
}
ul.about-div li.active h3 span {
  font-size: 11px; 
  line-height: 12px;
  color: #646464; 
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="about-div">
  <li class="active">
    <img src="http://oi64.tinypic.com/v7qo8h.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>User <span>My Profile</span></h3>    
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hey, exactly what I was trying to do. Can you put this in fiddle pleasE?

Comment: What happens when the span has a bigger value say a couple of sentences?